# Sharing app settings between modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, configuration, configuration-files

I'm not sure if i'm taking the wrong practice to this approach but I have a model & collection package i'm writing (exposing mongodb results as a model), and i'm trying to take a modular approach to it, however in the models, there's settings such as `host`, `port`, `password` ect that I think shouldn't be hard-coded into the modules.

My app has a `app.config` object that allows you to get certain settings, and I want to be able to use that in the model modules, but I don't want to be requiring modules as: `require('models/user')(app.config)` in a script every time I need the user model, because that just leads to code repetition.

**Here are a few solutions I've thought of:**

- Registrar

  - Create a object called `app.models` and assign all models and pass settings to them in a startup module
  - Disadvantage: I'd prefer to `require` model modules in files
- Global Config

  - Create a global variable linked to the `app.config`, which can be accessed in any module.
  - Disadvantage: Can't create multiple apps in the same process :(

Comment: Usually I would go with global config, but you mention `Can't create multiple apps in the same process`. I am not sure what it means, do you want to dynamic settings and create app dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

You could put the config in its own file, and import/require it from each model.

For example, in `models/user`...

```
const config = require('config')
```

...and wherever you're setting `app.config`...

```
app.config = require('config')
```

Comment: Thanks, but my config object is a part function which needs to be set up in the app startup (eg: `app.config = require('./config')(basedir)`)

Comment: You could do something like `const config = require('./config'); config.basedir = basedir`. You'd need to ensure that anything using the config at the top-level of the module is required after setting the config.